# How to test for hovering over a link, and if so, get the element's href

Tags: javascript, iframe, hyperlink, addeventlistener

I am working heavily with iframes, and would like to know if this is possible. Say there is an input with id search. If I hovered over a link (in an iframe) then is it possible to make it so the input would update via some event listener? I am okay with jQuery although I always prefer JS without any libraries. 
 If it isn't possible it's OK with me. Just wanted to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this something you can do with onmouseover? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp

```
<a href="click" onmouseover="hoverMe(this)">Click!</a>

<script>
function hoverMe(x) {
    console.log(x);
}

</script>
```

Then just open a document.write with the iframe to write the function hoverMe to all links.